# Printing type definitions from programmatically created AST

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am trying to programmatically create a typescript AST for definitions created by a third party library, and use that AST to print the set of type definitions (a .d.ts file) for the declarations we have in the syntax of the library.

Relying on the [documentation for the compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#creating-and-printing-a-typescript-ast), and digging through the source files for the typescript compiler, I believe that I have an AST that is mostly correct. However, I have not found a way to output the type definitions (corresponding to a .d.ts file) for this AST, only printing the AST as a typescript program.

My question is really two parts:

1. Is there a way to print the type definitions (output a .d.ts file) from the AST?
2. And if so, are there any examples of this?

Comment: The only thing I can find is `emitDeclarationFileOrBundle` in `emitter.ts`, but it does not take in any AST, it needs AST for complete source file (`SourceFile`).

Comment: I guess that's another part of the question, how do I create a source file programmatically? I tried going down that route, but I haven't been successful yet.

Comment: is not clear what do you want to do. Do you want to know the kind of each node in your ast ? then use astNode.kind.
Do you want to infer the type of a symbol in the file ? that's another thing, for that you use the following: 
```
export function getTypeFor(node: ts.Node, program: ts.Program): ts.Type {
  return program.getTypeChecker().getTypeAtLocation(node)
}```
Not answering because not sure what do you want, good luck

Comment: I know the AST nodes, because I create the AST, but I want to generate a definition file (a .d.ts file) from the AST.

Comment: I have a couple of questions for clarification: 1) it sounds like you've used the TS compiler API (not a hand-rolled AST type) to construct your AST. Have I understood that right? 2) it sounds like your AST contains both declarations and implementations, but you want to print out only the declarations. Have I understood you correctly? 3) Is your AST fully annotated, or do you need to infer types for some of the symbols in your program? The latter is harder, as indicated by @cancerbero.

Comment: I'm no expert in the TS compiler API, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's no built in way to print out only the declarations from an AST. You probably need to do it yourself. That'd involve writing an AST traversal which rubs out the implementations (and convert the headers to `declare` headers, ie `namespace` -> `declare namespace` etc). There's probably some sort of "visitor" infrastructure provided by the TS compiler to help you write these traversals. This is all guesswork

Comment: I am using the TS Compiler API to construct the AST. The AST contains only declarations because we are creating the declarations for types defined by the third party library we use. The AST is fully annotated.

Comment: I have my eye on the `emit` function in the Compiler API since it allows passing in a flag for `emitOnlyDtsFiles` which sounds exactly like that I want.

Comment: If your AST contains only declarations, then just printing out the string representation of that AST using `printer.printNode` should be exactly what you want I think? Perhaps I haven't understood your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to copy and alter what's done in the [`ts.transpileModule`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/865b3e786277233585e1586edba52bf837b61b71/src/services/transpile.ts#L26) function of the TypeScript source to only output the declaration file.

For example:

```
export function transpileModuleDeclaration(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile, transpileOptions: ts.TranspileOptions) {
    const diagnostics: ts.Diagnostic[] = [];
    const options = transpileOptions.compilerOptions != null ? { ...transpileOptions.compilerOptions } : ts.getDefaultCompilerOptions();

    options.isolatedModules = true;

    // in this case we only want to emit the declaration file
    options.emitDeclarationOnly = true;
    options.declaration = true;

    // this does not write anything to disk so there is no need to verify that there are no conflicts between input and output paths.
    options.suppressOutputPathCheck = true;

    // Filename can be non-ts file.
    options.allowNonTsExtensions = true;

    // We are not returning a sourceFile for lib file when asked by the program,
    // so pass --noLib to avoid reporting a file not found error.
    options.noLib = true;

    // Clear out other settings that would not be used in transpiling this module
    options.lib = undefined;
    options.types = undefined;
    options.noEmit = undefined;
    options.noEmitOnError = undefined;
    options.paths = undefined;
    options.rootDirs = undefined;
    options.composite = undefined;
    options.declarationDir = undefined;
    options.out = undefined;
    options.outFile = undefined;

    // We are not doing a full typecheck, we are not resolving the whole context,
    // so pass --noResolve to avoid reporting missing file errors.
    options.noResolve = true;

    // if jsx is specified then treat file as .tsx
    const inputFileName = transpileOptions.fileName || (options.jsx ? "module.tsx" : "module.ts");
    if (transpileOptions.moduleName) {
        sourceFile.moduleName = transpileOptions.moduleName;
    }

    // Output
    let outputText: string | undefined;

    // Create a compilerHost object to allow the compiler to read and write files
    const compilerHost: ts.CompilerHost = {
        getSourceFile: (fileName) => fileName === inputFileName.replace(/\\/g, "/") ? sourceFile : undefined,
        writeFile: (name, text) => {
            outputText = text;
        },
        getDefaultLibFileName: () => "lib.d.ts",
        useCaseSensitiveFileNames: () => false,
        getCanonicalFileName: fileName => fileName,
        getCurrentDirectory: () => "",
        getNewLine: () => options.newLine == null || options.newLine === ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed ? "\n" : "\r\n",
        fileExists: fileName => fileName === inputFileName,
        readFile: () => "",
        directoryExists: () => true,
        getDirectories: () => []
    };

    const program = ts.createProgram([inputFileName], options, compilerHost);

    if (transpileOptions.reportDiagnostics) {
        diagnostics.push(...program.getSyntacticDiagnostics(sourceFile));
        diagnostics.push(...program.getOptionsDiagnostics());
    }
    // Emit
    program.emit(/*targetSourceFile*/ undefined, /*writeFile*/ undefined, /*cancellationToken*/ undefined, /*emitOnlyDtsFiles*/ undefined, transpileOptions.transformers);

    if (outputText === undefined)
        throw new Error("Output generation failed.");

    return { outputText, diagnostics };
}
```

Then using it:

```
const file = ts.createSourceFile("test.ts", `function myFunc(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
}`, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, true);

const result = transpileModuleDeclaration(file, {});
console.log(result.outputText);
```

Outputs:

```
declare function myFunc(a: number, b: number): number;
```